# find a file with specific extension type then execute linux commands using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I want to use Python3 to backup a `.tar` file this `.tar` will be generated automatically by another program. For me to start the backup script, it has to check first if the `*.tar` exist then I will execute other commands like `cp` or `mv`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would be better to use python's built in file operations to move/copy files rather than cp/mv see https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: i'm actually trying those `os.system` so before executing this line: 
`os.system('gsutil cp ~/$name.tar gs://bucket/$name.tar')`

I want the script to find the specific file first

Comment: @erlchamp
Please accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import walk

path = '/path/to/directory'  # the directory path that you want to search in
dir_path, dir_names, file_names = next(walk(path))  # You need file_names
for file_name in filenames:
    if '.tar' in file_name:  # or if os.path.splitext(path)[-1] == '.tar'
        <your backup process codes>
```